# How to create an authentication system with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, authorization

I read the Spring Security documentation to learn how to create a basic authentication system for my web application but I don't understand what architecture to pick.
Link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#preface

Currently I'm using the class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with this code :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index", "/user/**").permitAll()       
                //.antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")          
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error") 
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

But in the documentation they recommand 3 alternative solutions.

1) WebMvcConfigurer : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration

2) AuthenticationManager :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-authentication

3) With another classes designed for Web Application (?)
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-web-authentication

So, it's currently a big mess in my head and I don't know at all how to create my authentication system.
What architecture am I supposed to choose ?

Here my other classes in addition to understand my project :

UserService

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import app.shellx.dao.AuthorityRepository;
import app.shellx.dao.RoleRepository;
import app.shellx.dao.UserRepository;
import app.shellx.model.Authority;
import app.shellx.model.Role;
import app.shellx.model.User;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public User loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        //List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getAuthorities());
        //if you're implementing UserDetails you wouldn't need to call this method and instead return the User as it is
        //return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        return user;

    }

    /*public User login() {
         try {
                Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
                Authentication result = am.authenticate(request);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
                break;
            } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
                System.out.println("Authentication failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully authenticated. Security context contains: " +
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        }
    }*/

    /* // Converts user to spring.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    private User buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities, user.isAccountNonExpired(), user.getAvatar());
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<Authority> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        // add user's authorities
        for (Authority userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList()<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }*/

    public void add(User user, String role) {
        user.setRole(roleService.findByRole(role));
        this.userRepository.save(user);
        /*role.setAuthorities(authorities);
        this.roleRepository.save(role);
        for (Authority auth : authorities) {
            auth.setRoles(role);
            this.authorityRepository.save(auth);
        }*/
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public String getCurrentUser() {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username;

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((User)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }

        return username;
    }
}
```

User

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "users_username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "users_email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "users_password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "users_enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(name = "users_avatar")
    private String avatar;
    @Column(name = "users_date")
    private LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JoinTable(name = "authorities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_username"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roles_username"))
    private Role role;


    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password, boolean enabled, String avatar) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password, Role role, boolean enabled, String avatar) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }



    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();
        authorities = role.getAuthorities();
        return authorities;
    }
    public void setName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }   
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }   
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }   
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }   

    public String getRoleRole() {
        return role.getRole();
    }
}
```

EDIT : I'm using SPRING BOOT and Hibernate

Comment: For your first part, WebMvcConfigurer, it is just a configuration which enable mvc architecture (Model , controller and View).
For your security part you have web security configurer adapter (one you have created), spring security handles most of your authentication part with minimal configuration and is powerful.

Comment: @Akash Ok, but in this part where is the AuthenticationManager, SecurityContext, Authentication built with an User object from database, etc. ? It's the mechanism behind I don't get it.